# Persistence and choice between vanilla GARCH and component-GARCH

Tags: time-series, model-selection, garch

I have a question regarding the interpretation of the component GARCH model, and hypotheses related to its possible improvement over the simple GARCH model. I'm doing some time series analysis and a GARCH(1,1) model on the data produces $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coefficients that add to 0.92 ($\alpha$ of 0.15 and $\beta$ of 0.77). Now, from what I know the interpretation of $\alpha+\beta$ is that numbers closer to 1 mean more persistence in the volatility of the time series (and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of course each have their own interpretations regarding the nature of the volatility. In my case it looks like the data has a high vol-of-vol). My first **question**: is there some objective level or even subjective ranges for the strength of the persistence in regards to this number? Is 0.92 considered very persistent, or not?

Secondly, regarding the component GARCH model, from what I know this is supposed to do a better job of modeling long-run persistence relationships. Therefore, do the coefficients of a simple GARCH(1,1) model give insight to when using the cGARCH extension could prove useful? As it relates to my data, the specific **question** is, given the coefficients I have found in the GARCH(1,1) model, do these give any motivation to consider using a component GARCH model?

Answer (score 1):

Many component-GARCH models seen in the literature (the Engle and Lee (1999) model, the spline-GARCH of Engle and Rangel (2008), TV-GARCH model of Amado and Teräsvirta (2013), GARCH-MIDAS-RV model, etc.) have been motivated by the necessity to account for the evident long-range dependence in financial market volatility or the 'IGARCH' effect.

The geometric decay of the autocorrelation function of conditional volatility implied by a standard, stationary GARCH model is not in line with empirical observations (often a hyperbolic decay is observed).

The 'low' persistence found may indicate that a more advanced GARCH specification is unnecessary, but formal testing procedure can be applied.

See also this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3071822) written by myself.